# Case-insensitive URI with nginx and tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, https

Application is deployed on tomcat and nginx used in front of that.All requests are taken by nginx and passed onto Tomcat.
**Redirect to nginx but not to tomcat.How to get the request at tomcat.?**

At nginx side handling url case insensitive using code in nginx config
//config file code

```
location ~* "^/[Aa][Bb][Cc]/(.*)$"
    {       
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8008/abc/$1?$args;
        }
```

**The remaining part is handled at tomcat
I have one filter class where I'm getting requested uri and converting it to lowercase and forwarding requested uri.**

```
@WebFilter("/AuthenticationFilter")
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String url =request.getRequestURI();
        String uri =request.getRequestURI() +(request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : "");

        if (!url.toLowerCase().equals(url))
        {
            String newURI = uri.toLowerCase();
            HttpServletRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new RequestUriChangingWrapper(request, newURI);

            if(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST"))
            {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder (1000);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(req.getInputStream ());

                while (scanner.hasNextLine())
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine());
                }
                wrappedRequest. setAttribute ("login_param", stringBuilder.toString());
            }
            else
            {
                //response.sendRedirect(newURI); it sends "redirect" command on browser. So browser will try to ask "127.0.0.1" on itself computer ))
            }

            RequestDispatcher
            dispatcher = wrappedRequest. getRequestDispatcher (request.getScheme() + "://" + request. getServerName () + newURI);
            dispatcher . forward (wrappedRequest, response);
        }
        else
        {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //
    }

    public class RequestUriChangingWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        private String originalValue;
        private String newValue;
        public RequestUriChangingWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String newValue) {
            super(request);
            this.newValue = newValue;
            this.originalValue = request.getRequestURI();
        }
        public String getRequestURI() {

                return newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've not got experience with nginx, but I would have thought you'd better of with a rewrite rule on your http server rather than a filter.